# Empty/delete a set in Redis?

Tags: set, redis

Maybe I'm just blind, but I don't see an explicit [set command](http://redis.io/commands#set) in Redis for emptying an existing set (without emptying the entire database). For the time being, I'm doing a set difference on the set with itself and storing it back into itself:

```
redis> SMEMBERS metasyn
1) "foo"
2) "bar"
redis> SDIFFSTORE metasyn metasyn metasyn
(integer) 0
redis> SMEMBERS metasyn
(empty list or set)
```

But that looks a little silly... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I liked your creativity in that

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You could delete the set altogether with [`DEL`](http://redis.io/commands/del).

```
DEL metasyn
```

From redis console,

```
redis> SMEMBERS metasyn
1) "foo"
2) "bar"
redis> DEL metasyn
(integer) 1
redis> SMEMBERS metasyn
(empty list or set)
```

Comment: Wow guess I should have tried that first, haha. For some reason I thought that command didn't apply to sets. Thanks!

Comment: yeah it took me a while to figure that one too.. the commands in [`Keys`](http://redis.io/commands#generic) apply globally to all keys regardless of data type.

Comment: I see; I suppose that makes sense. Ah well, I'll leave this embarrassing question up for the next fool like me who didn't bother with the [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro). :-)

Comment: And I would be that fool because why would you want to keep an empty set in memory...

Comment: Because an empty set means something different from a non existent set.  Consider: newuser111:questions (the set of questions by new user 111) vs. nonexistentuser:questions (supposedly the set of questions by nonexistentuser, a user that does not exist). It's useful to have an empty set to distinguish between the two.