# How to remove redis zset?

Tags: redis

I have key "test", the type is zset, I want to remove it.Its value is complex.

```
    127.0.0.1:6379>zrange test 1 2
    1) "\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x04bodyq\x02U\x00U\t_encodingq\x03U\x05utf-8q\x04U\acookiesq\x05}q\x06U\x04metaq\a}q\bU\x05depthq\tK\x01sU\aheadersq\n}q\x0bU\aRefererq\x0c]q\rU.http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,002273,f_1.htmlq\x0easU\x03urlq\x0fX0\x00\x00\x00http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,002273,f_334.htmlU\x0bdont_filterq\x10\x89U\bpriorityq\x11K\x00U\bcallbackq\x12U\x05parseq\x13U\x06methodq\x14U\x03GETq\x15U\aerrbackq\x16Nu."
    2) "\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x04bodyq\x02U\x00U\t_encodingq\x03U\x05utf-8q\x04U\acookiesq\x05}q\x06U\x04metaq\a}q\bU\x05depthq\tK\x01sU\aheadersq\n}q\x0bU\aRefererq\x0c]q\rU.http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,002273,f_1.htmlq\x0easU\x03urlq\x0fX0\x00\x00\x00http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,002273,f_335.htmlU\x0bdont_filterq\x10\x89U\bpriorityq\x11K\x00U\bcallbackq\x12U\x05parseq\x13U\x06methodq\x14U\x03GETq\x15U\aerrbackq\x16Nu."
    127.0.0.1:6379>zcard test
    57232
```

There are so many values, I want to remove them all or some. How can I do this?

Comment: `DEL test` will do the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty/delete a set in Redis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301399/empty-delete-a-set-in-redis)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [DEL](http://redis.io/commands/del) command to remove any key from redis database, regardless of the datatype associated with it.

> **DEL key [key ...]**
>
> Removes the specified keys. A key is ignored if it does not exist.

Answer (score 10):

`DEL` will allow you to remove the key entirely: http://redis.io/commands/del.

`ZREM` will allow you to remove members from the set: http://redis.io/commands/zrem.

There are additional `ZREM*` commands that allow the removal of ranges of members - see `ZREMRANGEBYLEX`, `ZREMRANGEBYRANK` and `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`

Answer (score 2):

You use the "del" command to remove an entry from redis:

```
del test
```

See: http://redis.io/commands/del