# Delete All keys of a Set in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I wonder is there any method to completely delete a set in the `StackExchange.Redis` library?

As I know there is a method in Redis :
[Empty/delete a set in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301399/empty-delete-a-set-in-redis)

Thanks

Comment: `"is there any method to completely delete a Set..."` -- You literally linked to a question that tells you to use [`DEL`](https://redis.io/commands/del).  What are you actually asking then because I do not understand your issue.

Comment: I want a method in `StackExchange.Redis` library not a command in Redis.

Comment: I believe you want `KeyDelete`.  As seen in the [github repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/0542bc9c34a5685fef17d74e567deb216db71390/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/Interfaces/IDatabase.cs) the comments for this method indicate its the same as [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del)

Comment: `KeyDelete` just deletes a single Key/Value, I want to delete a `Set` with all keys inside it.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Based on the question you linked ‘DEL setName’ should work.  I know the documentation says “Key” but the docs also say this is equivalent to DEL

Comment: @maccettura It worked,

Comment: awesome. Glad to hear! I’m going to add the solution as an answer in case anyone else runs into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyDelete` method should be what you’re looking for.  As seen in the [repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/0542bc9c34a5685fef17d74e567deb216db71390/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/Interfaces/IDatabase.cs) the comments indicate it functions the same as [`DEL`](https://redis.io/commands/del)